# Scala method which accepts multiple different objects, all of which extend the same trait

Tags: scala, class, traits

I have a `trait` `Document[T]`, and two case classes which extend that trait:

```
Memo(...) extends Document[Memo]
Fax(...) extends Document[Fax]
```

Each represents a different type of text file.

I want to clean these documents using some text tools, but creating a method that takes both types has vexed me.

```
val rawText: Seq[String]
// The text of all documents where one string in the sequence is the text of one document

val documentType = "Memo"
// Can also be "Fax"

val documentObjects = documentType match {
case "Memo" => rawText.map(_.makeMemoDocument) // results in Seq[Memo]
case "Fax" => rawText.map(_.makeFaxDocument) // results in Seq[Fax]
}

// Here lies my dilemma...
def processDocuments(docs: Seq[Document[T]]): Seq[Document[T]] = {...}

val processedDocs = processDocuments(documentObjects)
```

I want to define `documentObjects` in a way so that it can be easily accepted by `processDocuments`, i.e. `processDocuments` should accept either a `Seq[Memo]` or a `Seq[Fax]` as an argument.

I am creating case classes to be run through a Stanford CoreNLP pipeline, and I want to be able to support adding multiple case classes extending the `Document[T]` trait in the future (e.g. later on, add support for `Pamphlet(...) extends Document[Pamphlet]`).

Any help would be appreciated. If you require more information, I'd be happy to provide it.

Comment: Are your sure you need **F-Bounded Polymorphism**, I mean, do you really need your document to extend itself, like in `class Memo(...) extends Document[Memo]`? - Anyways, if yes, you can write your method like `def processDocuments[T <: Document[T]](docs: Seq[T]): Seq[T]`

Answer (score 1):

```
val documentObjects:Document[_] = documentType match {
   case "Memo" => rawText.map(_.makeMemoDocument) // results in Seq[Memo]
   case "Fax" => rawText.map(_.makeFaxDocument) // results in Seq[Fax]
}

def processDocuments[T](docs: Seq[Document[T]]): Seq[Document[T]] = ???
val processedDocs = processDocuments(Seq(documentObjects))
```

or remove type declaration on `documentObjects` and use

```
def processDocuments(docs: Seq[Document[_]]): Seq[Document[_]] = ???
//or
def processDocuments[T <: Document[_]](docs: Seq[T]): Seq[T]= ???
```